# PHP Goutte. Select button without "value" field

Tags: php, html, goutte

This is my target website: http://www.rapid7.com/db/ and I want to carry out a search there, let's say the string "Symphony" to check out its vulnerabilities.

Inspecting the elements of input form I see that its name is "q", so far so good, but the button has no value, instead the button I need to submit my query is: `<span id="run_search" class="vbsearchBtn"></span>` without the value field.

My code:

```
$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.rapid7.com/db/');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('????')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('q' => 'Symphony'));
print $crawler->html();
```

Does anyone know how to carry this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand your problem is to get form element, why do you need button to do this? You can query form by id which is `<form id="search_form" ...>`. You may also want to submit `t` parameter which is database type you want to query (`a` for all `m` for modules `v` for vulnerabilities). Your code should be something like this (you need CssSelector component installed):

```
$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.rapid7.com/db/');
$form = $crawler->filter('#search_form')->first()->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('q' => 'Symphony', 't' => 'a'));
print $crawler->html();
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer but I get this error:  
  
`PHP Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client::submit() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Form, instance of Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler given, called in /root/PHP/testrapid72.php on line 20 and defined in phar:///root/PHP/goutte.phar/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/Browse‌​rKit/Client.php on line 267` I have never seen this way of selecting the form, it makes sense but doesn't work for me, have you tried it yourself¿?

Comment: Thank you very much, I did this this way:
`$client = new Client();

            $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.rapid7.com/db/');
            $form = $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@class="searchContainer"]/form')->form();
            $crawler = $client->submit($form, array('q' => 'Drupal', 't' => 'a'));
            print $crawler->html();`